# Where are Salesforce Functions?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforce-functions

So, we hear all the noise about 'evergreen' / Salesforce Functions (or whatever the new name is) and we go wild with excitement.

Where is all this stuff? We (our organization) are on Spring '21. Is this functionality supposed to be out? I understand it to be in Beta.

There is no sfdx tooling available. There is no documentation. Links that 'used' to work to high level documentation now simply give a 404.

Have I misunderstood something somewhere along the line?

Is anyone using Salesforce Functions?

Winter '22 update :
and here we are in Winter '22 and STILL NO?

Is anyone actually using salesforce functions in Winter 22?
We do not set the 'Enable Functions' button in Setup.
Is this actually GA yet?

Perhaps I should just give up :(

Comment: Are you referring to something like what's in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zkyQ9MK6eYU)?

Comment: The Spring 21 Release Notes are currently "missing in action", so I can't confirm if it actually did go public with this release. I've asked the doc team to see what we can do to get it fixed. Last I heard, tooling was a hidden plugin, orgs had to be "blessed" with the feature, and documentation was on a password-protected site. I'd expect it to still be pilot until at least Summer 21; even the pilot is relatively new. Where did you hear it was going beta this release?

Comment: Yes, Adrian, that's exactly what I'm talking about. I saw that video shortly after it was released (August 2020), which is about the time all sorts of stuff was flying around about the wonderfulness of salesforce functions. But it's got awol :) It had been promised ad nauseam that is was to be released as a beta in Spring '21...

Comment: "Where did I hear it was going beta this release?" No, joke. Not two weeks ago I could click on ANY Release Notes for Spring '21 link and I would see references to the 'Salesforce Functions' beta that was to be included with the release. Now? errr .. either the link is busted, or if it's not, there is no reference to Salesforce Functions at all. Twilight Zone I'm thinking, or I've just lost it. But I know I haven't. Even my manager said to keep an eye out for this in Spring 21. There is some fishiness underfoot :) (If this stuff is not ready, that's fine, but I wish they would simply tell us)

Answer (score 16):

**Update**

Functions is GA as of 12th October 2021. Note it wont be available in Developer Edition orgs as of now but there will be a Trial edition orgs later this year.

You can read more about Functions launch using below link

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/10/salesforce-functions-is-generally-available

As per the release notes docs [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring21/release-notes/rn_forcecom_functions.htm) quoting the sentence

> The Salesforce Functions beta is planning to open after the release of Salesforce Spring ’21. Look for further announcements and details on developer.salesforce.com and in the Salesforce Functions Trailblazer Community.

So we will have to wait for announcements from the team on [developer.salesforce.com](https://developer.salesforce.com) to see when this is available.

Meanwhile, if you are curious and missed Dreamforce 2021 then the below sessions should be good to watch

[1. Salesforce Functions Demo](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/sessions?eventId=a1Q4V00002DWxkY#/session/a2q4V000001LvPEQA0)

[2. Build Connected Experiences](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/sessions?eventId=a1Q4V00002DWxkY#/session/a2q4V000002BOA4QAO)

Comment: Thanks Mohith, So it says "Use" this feature at your sole discretion", but of course, as you mentioned, it 'now' says (which I'm sure it didn't 2 weeks ago :) that a beta is "planning to open 'after' Spring '21 ". So, Salesforce Functions has nothing to do with Spring '21 and is in the Spring '21 release notes.. I give up....

Comment: @PeterByrne It's been always like this in the release notes from the beginning when it was drafted.  There is a change log that would otherwise have mentioned. https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring21/release-notes/rn_change_log.htm#rn_change_log

Comment: OK mate, my bad. Thanks for the update. I guess I'll just wait then for whenever this becomes available.........

Comment: .... and I'll keep waiting I guess. Summer '21 release notes are out and the blurb regarding 'Salesforce Functions' is basically a copy/paste of Spring '21. I guess I am grateful that Salesforce are not releasing a product until it's ready, but I'd like to voice my opinion that it is seems rather disingenuous to be making all the noise that was made about this (very cool) concept in what? 2019? ........        and still nothing?

Comment: @PeterByrne I understand your frustration! The team wants to make sure the product is really really good and scalable to meet large needs!

Comment: The Winter 22 release notes mentions Salesforce Functions and (I think) we should have access now? Would be nice to have some sort of a documentation on how to enable or use the feature

Comment: @HaroutTatarian Its not available in Dev Orgs. Only available in PROD and you will need to reach your AE to get it activated . There will be Trial orgs later this year

Comment: Is this something that ISVs will be able to use in managed packages later on or are the functions only accessible in the prod org they’re developed for?

Comment: @HaroutTatarian Not at this point.

Comment: You can use Functions locally (trigger from the CLI), against a Dev Org without a license. I wrote a blog post about it. [Getting Started with Salesforce Functions Locally. No License Required!](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/11/getting-started-with-salesforce-functions-locally-no-license-required)